# Firebase token management in servers

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I still new with firebase and android notifications. I want to be able to send notifications to a single user based on some rules. What I've been reading so far is that a token can be generated with:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()
```

Then, the token will need to be refreshed at some point when it expires.

How to I set expiry for these tokens, if at all possible? If there are a thousand users having their tokens refreshed around the same time then I will need to do a thousand writes for these tokens to my app servers. Is there a known scaling solution for this problem (eg. keep the same token but refresh its expiry only)?

Answer (score 3):

The [Firebase documentation on monitoring the token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) enumerates the reasons:

> The registration token may change when:
>
> - The app deletes Instance ID
> - The app is restored on a new device
> - The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
> - The user clears app data.

Beyond deleting the token (the first option above), you have no control over when a token is refreshed. But unlike Firebase Authentication tokens, the Instance ID Tokens of Firebase Cloud Messaging don't refresh on a fixed schedule. Instance ID Token refreshes are relatively rare and should only need special considering for scaling out in the largest use-cases.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. There is no way to just refresh the *expiration* of a registration token.

When a registration token is *refreshed*, the token value will change. The event when the registration token itself will *expire* is indefinite as well and can only happen on specific events as specified in the [FirebaseInstanceId docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId):

> Instance ID is stable except when:
>
> - App deletes Instance ID
> - App is restored on a new device
> - User uninstalls/reinstall the app
> - User clears app data
>
> In the above cases a new Instance ID is generated and the application needs to recreate the authorization tokens previously generated implementing [onTokenRefresh()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService#onTokenRefresh()).

And as already mentioned above, in the event where a token is refreshed, `onTokenRefresh()` will be called and that you should handle the next steps on sending it to your App Server and deleting the old token that got expired and some other stuff.