# Firebase Token Validity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am generating firebase token using the following line of code

```
String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

I get the token , which I store in the database. I'am able to use this to send notification to individual devices.

But after a few days I get the message as 'Unregistered registration token' and the notification is not delivered.

can you please solve the problem.

Also is there a way to check the validity/registration of a token in firebase console?

Answer (score 0):

New Firebase token is generated (onTokenRefresh() is called) when:

The app deletes Instance ID
The app is restored on a new device
The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
The user clears app data.

Refer this :

[Firebase Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787373/firebase-fcm-how-to-get-token)

Comment: But if nothing of the above is done , how long will the firebase token be valid.

Comment: validation of token is about 1 hour....

Comment: you can check using ....public static boolean hasValidAuthToken() {
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null ? true : false;
}

Comment: @Ashish Firebase Authentication tokens are valid for one hours and auto-refresh. But Firebase Cloud Messaging/Instance Id tokens don't have a specific invalidation interval and typically remain valid **much** longer. For a list of the very specific cases when the token is refreshed, see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628749/firebase-token-management-in-servers/40632811#40632811) or the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register).